# how to work out a closed form of a sequence

Tags: recurrence-relations

> Consider the following linear recurrence sequence.

$x_1 = 11$,  $x_{n+1} = -0.8x_n + 9,\quad n = 1,2,3, \ldots.$

Find a closed form for this sequence.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation#Solving_non-homogeneous_recurrence_relations

Comment: You should really try to write out the first few terms and see what happens if you have nowhere to go.

Answer (score 2):

To get an idea of what the closed form might look like, let's iterate the relation a few times:
$$
\begin{align}
x_n
&=9-.8x_{n-1}\\
&=9-.8(9-.8x_{n-2})\\
&=9-.8\cdot9+.8^2x_{n-2}\\
&=9-.8\cdot9+.8^2(9-.8x_{n-3})\\
&=9-.8\cdot9+.8^2\cdot9-.8^3x_{n-3}\tag{1}
\end{align}
$$
Looking at $(1)$, it appears that
$$
x_n=9\frac{1-(-.8)^k}{1+.8}+(-.8)^kx_{n-k}\tag{2}
$$
Equation $(2)$ can be verified using induction.

---

**Verification:** The case $k=1$ is just the given recursion: $x_n=9-.8x_{n-1}$.

Suppose $(2)$ is true for some $k$, then
$$
\begin{align}
x_n
&=9\frac{1-(-.8)^k}{1+.8}+(-.8)^kx_{n-k}\\
&=9\frac{1-(-.8)^k}{1+.8}+(-.8)^k(9-.8x_{n-k-1})\\
&=9\frac{1-(-.8)^k}{1+.8}+9(-.8)^k+(-.8)^{k+1}x_{n-k-1}\\
&=9\frac{1-(-.8)^{k+1}}{1+.8}+(-.8)^{k+1}x_{n-k-1}\\
\end{align}
$$
So $(2)$ is true for $k+1$.

---

Using $x_1=11$ and $k=n-1$, $(2)$ becomes
$$
\begin{align}
x_n
&=5(1-(-.8)^{n-1})+(-.8)^{n-1}11\\
&=5+6(-.8)^{n-1}\tag{3}
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 1):

$x_{n+1}+a=-0.8(x_n+a)$

if a=-5, this equation is equivalent to $x_{n+1}=-0.8x_n+9$

then we obtain:

$x_n-5=(-0.8)^{n-1}(x_1-5)$

Thus:

$x_n=5+6(-0.8)^{n-1}$

Answer (score 0):

Use generating functions. Define $X(z) = \sum_{n \ge 0} x_{n + 1} z^n$, multiply the recurrence by $z^n$ and sum over $n \ge 0$ to get:
$$
\frac{X(z) - x_1}{z} = - \frac{4 X(z)}{5} + \frac{9}{1 - z}
$$
Thus:
$$
X(z) = \frac{55 - 10 z}{5 - z - 4 z^2}
     = 5 \cdot \frac{1}{1 - z} + 6 \cdot \frac{1}{1 + 4 z / 5}
$$
Two geometric series:
$$
x_{n + 1} = 5 + 6 \cdot (-0.8)^n
$$